# Azure Table Store etag

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Storage SDK for Java https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java.
It works like this:

```
CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference()
TableOperation retrieve =
                TableOperation.retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey, type);
cloudTable.execute(retrieve).getResultAsType()
```

Is there any way to pass en ETag as "If-None-Match: myETag" when retrieving records from a table? This way i'd like to get HTTP 304. Would it make this thing any faster?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to pass en ETag as "If-None-Match: myETag" when
>   retrieving records from a table?

No. At this time use of `Etag` for managing optimistic concurrency is applicable only for `Update` operations (which include [`Update Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179427.aspx) and [`Merge Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179392.aspx)) & [`Delete Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135727.aspx) operation.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179371.aspx says there are some additional headers for blobs. Is there any way to use it with Azure Storage java sdk?

Comment: Those are for blob service and not tables. For blobs, you can use this header for GET operations but not for tables. HTH.